# How do I test/compare/argument match stdClass arguments to be passed to SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, simplexml, stdclass

My background is Java. I somehow thought diving into PHP would be fun.

I have a WSDL file with a few methods defined that I need to call. Each method typically has one request and one response type defined. These types are all one or two levels deep, no attributes - only elements. Nothing fancy.
Almost all methods requires some common arguments, like "username" and "password".

I thought I'd test drive all of this and so I created an indirection which handles passing the standard arguments. The production code looks something like this:

```php
class PaymentManager implements IPaymentManager {

  public function __construct($soapClient, $username, $password, ...) {
    $this->soapClient = $soapClient; 
    $this->username = $username;
    ...
  }

  public function chargeCustomer($price, $customerId) {
    // prepare message
    $message = new stdClass();
    $message->ChargeMethodRequest = new stdClass();
    $message->ChargeMethodRequest->Username   = $this->username;
    $message->ChargeMethodRequest->Password   = $this->password;
    $message->ChargeMethodRequest->Price      = $price;
    $message->ChargeMethodRequest->CustomerID = $customerId;

    // make the actual call
    $result = $this->soapClient->chargeMethod($message->ChargeMethodRequest);

    // verify successful result
    if ($result->ChargeMethodResponse->Result === "SUCCESS") {
      throw new Exception("whopsie");
    }
  }
```

Now, the trick is to write a unit test for this without needing to use a real instance of SoapClient. I started out with SoapUI and generated example messages, but them in a PHP file as static strings that I can reference from the unit test. So I imagine something like this:

```php
class WebServiceClientTest extends DrupalUnitTestCase /* yup, sad and true */ {

  public function test_charge_method_happy_path() {
    $soapClientMock = new SoapClientMock();
    $testee = new WebServiceClient($soapClientMock, $un, $pw, ...); 

    // arrange
    $successResponse = parseToStdClass(WebServiceClientMessages::RESPONSE_OK);
    $expectedMessage = parseToStdClass(WebServiceClientMessages::REQUEST_EXAMPLE_1);
    given($soapClientMock->chargeMethod($expectedMessage))->willReturn($successResponse);

    // act
    $testee->chargeCustomer("10.00", "customerId123");

    // assert
    verify($soapClientMock).chargeMethod($expectedMessage);
  }
}
```

First attempt, Phockito: failed since SoapClient is a "native" class and those can't be used with `Reflection*` in PHP.

Failing that, I wrote a `SoapClientMock` class that I want to stub methods calls to and also verify interactions. This is not a big deal but the problem is argument matching.

How can I take the example messages (XML strings), parse them into something that I can compare with the stdClass objects that the SoapClient needs in order to bind stuff correctly? From what I understand, object comparison is hard coded and looks if the two objects are of the same class.

SimpleXMLElement was my first hope, but that's not very easy to compare to the stdClass object mainly because of how SimpleXMLElement wants to use namespaces all around.

Serialization doesn't work because SimpleXMLElement objects are "native" classes.

Someone suggested doing `json_decode(json_encode($object))` and then compare that, and that almost worked except that SimpleXMLElement fails because there's no way to get child nodes without specifying a namespace (and there are more than one I need to use), so the `$expectedMessage` doesn't contain all the elements.

I'm currently writing my own "xml string to stdClass" parser using SAX.

But wait - all I wanted was to make sure the PaymentManager properly populates the payload for the chargeMethod - why did I end up writing a SAX parser.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one option is to let a `SoapClientSpyMockFakeSomething extends SoapClient` and override the `__doRequest` method and use the XML string you get there ...